# get values from array by condition

Tags: javascript

My data is in below format. Can I get list of employees with empStatus == 1 ?

```
[
    {
        "empName": "XXX",
        "empID": "34343",
        "empStatus": 1
    },
    {
        "empName": "XX",
        "empID": "5454345",
        "empStatus": 0
    },
    {
        "empName": "XXXXX",
        "empID": "6998977657",
        "empStatus": 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var employees = [
{
    "empName": "XXX",
    "empID": "34343",
    "empStatus": 1
},
{
    "empName": "XX",
    "empID": "5454345",
    "empStatus": 0
},
{
    "empName": "XXXXX",
    "empID": "6998977657",
    "empStatus": 1
}
];

var statusOneEmployees = employees.filter(function(item) {
  return item.empStatus === 1;
});

for(var i = 0; i < statusOneEmployees.length; i++) {
  document.write(statusOneEmployees[i].empID + "<br/>"); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use filter:

```
var b = arr.filter(function(obj,index){
    return obj.empStatus==1;
})
console.log(b)
```